# Relative horizontal centering of nodes in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, diagrams, nodes

These are two separate *but closely related* questions.

I have the following diagram:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage,tikz]{book}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1) [draw,rectangle] {Social change};
\node (2) [draw,rectangle,below=of 1] {Mobilizing structures};
\node (3) [draw,rectangle,below left=of 2] {Opportunity and threat};
\node (4) [draw,rectangle,below right=of 2] {Framing processes};
\node (5) [draw,rectangle,below=of $(3)!0.5!(4)$] {Repertoires of contention};
\node (6) [draw,rectangle,below=of 5] {Contentious interaction};
\end{tikzpicture}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. I don't need nodes 3 and 4 to be that far apart, i.e. I would like to have them positioned next to each other *right below node 2*. I understand that this undesired behaviour is precisely what the `below left` and `below right` options of the `positioning` library command, but not using those options would cause the two nodes to overlap.
2. I would like for nodes 5 and 6 to be horizontally centered, just like nodes 1 and 2. Using the `calc` library to calculate the middle point between nodes 3 and 4 (`$(3)!0.5!(4)$`) doesn't do the job since they are not simmetrical and their middle point is positioned left of the central axis.

In short, I am looking for a way to horizontally position nodes relative to the central axis of the diagram.

Comment: something like `\node (4) [draw,rectangle,below right=1 and -1 of 2] {Framing processes};
 \node (5) [draw,rectangle,below=3 of 2] {Repertoires of contention};`?

Comment: Yes, something like that, provided you also change node 3's positioning into `\node (3) [draw,rectangle,below left=1 and -1 of 2] {Opportunity and threat};` Incidentally, is it just my impression or the vertical distance between node 5 and the preceding two nodes is inevitably different than the standard distance when no specific value is given?

Comment: Because `$(3)!0.5!(4)$` is a **point**. You need to replace it by `$(3.south)!0.5!(4.south)$`. (Or `$(3.south east)!0.5!(4.south west)$`. Notice the difference.)

Comment: `\node (5) [draw,rectangle,below=of 3 -| 1] {Repertoires of contention};`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I think a `tikz matrix` is your friend.

I've given a name (`m`) to the matrix, so, in case you'll need to refer to your nodes, you can use `m-row_number-column_number`. For example, the "Social change" node is `m-1-2`.

If you want to increase the space between the rows, just change `row sep = 2ex`.

I have drawn all the nodes with the same width because they look better to me.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit, matrix}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, rectangle, text width= 12em,
text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,
align = center}, row sep = 2ex,column sep = -6em] (m) {%
& Social change \\
& Mobilizing structures \\
Opportunity and threat &&
Framing processes \\
& Repertoires of contention \\
& Contentious interaction \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to understand how `positioning` library works. Every potitioning option (`left, right, above left, ...`) uses a particular anchor (`east, west, south east,...`) from the node to be placed and from the reference node. But you can change them after positioning option with a new `anchor` declaration.

As an example, your `below left = of` places `3.north east` at default distance from `2.south west, but you could say`below left = of 2.south, anchor=north`which will place`3.north`at a below left distance position from`2.south`.

You can also define a `default` distance with two components (i.e. `2mm and 1cm`) where the first component will be used with horizontal and vertical positioning options (left, above, ...) and both for two components (`above right`).

With previous comments I hope you could understand following code.

More information about `positioning` library [here](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual#page=229).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3mm and 1mm]
\node (1) [draw,rectangle] {Social change};
\node (2) [draw,rectangle,below=of 1] {Mobilizing structures};
\node (3) [draw,rectangle,below left=of 2.south] {Opportunity and threat};
\node (4) [draw,rectangle,below right=of 2.south] {Framing processes};
\node (5) [draw,rectangle,below left= of 4, anchor=north]  {Repertoires of contention};
\node (6) [draw,rectangle,below=of 5] {Contentious interaction};
\end{tikzpicture}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]